# "mod_wsgi : Unable to import site module" in Apache Error Logs

Tags: python, django, apache, shared-libraries, mod-wsgi

I am working with mod_wsgi + Python2.7. After installing mod_wsgi, I restarted httpd. The following got printed to my Apache error log.

```
"mod_wsgi pid=XXXX" Unable to import 'site' module.
```

Hitting the IP-address yielded an

```
" Import error No module named os "
```

in the Apache error logs.

I have installed mod_wsgi using **yum install mod_wsgi**. I'm aware that the nicer way to install it is by compiling it from source using the preferred Python version.

(  However, doing so failed. Running a **make** after the **./configure** produced the following errors.

```
/usr/lib64/apr-1/build/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc -o mod_wsgi.la  -rpath /usr/lib64/httpd/modules -module -avoid-version    mod_wsgi.lo -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(node.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
.
make: *** [mod_wsgi.la] Error 1
```

)

Using leads from [Installation Issues](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues) , I checked whether my mod_wsgi.so installation  was OK.

Running a

```
ldd /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

Produced

```
[root@BLFLDT9454T mod_wsgi-3.4]# ldd /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
    libpython2.4.so.1.0 => /usr/lib64/libpython2.4.so.1.0 (0x00002b90b505d000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002b90b5392000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002b90b55ae000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00002b90b57b3000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002b90b59b6000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b90b5c39000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003530400000)
```

Which shows that shared libraries are in use already ( if I am not wrong ).

So where could I be going wrong?

Thanks, 
Shoubhik

Answer (score 0):

In the document you reference, it says the following:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues#Mixing_32_Bit_And_64_Bit_Packages

IOW. y Python installation has not been installed with --enable-shared when configure was run for Python.

Also, you do not seem to have removed the existing mod_wsgi properly either if what is installed is still referencing Python 2.4.